# How to open application/itunes store by one link?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have idea! E.g I send invite to application for my friend by email. I wanna have link in this email. When user will click it, he will open application, if it's installed, if it's not - show iTunes store. Any idea how to realize it?

[Communicating with Other Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

I begun to read this one, but didn't find solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I provide the method to check whether an app is installed on iphone.

If the URL scheme for your app is "myapp:", then

```
BOOL myAppInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"myapp:"]];
```

Comment: how "myapp:" will open iTunes store?